# Telegram bot should send URL that contains "&" character, but it sends the URL only until that character and then cuts it short

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want my Telegram bot to send a URL to a channel. However, the url contains the "&" character which cuts the message that it's trying to send short. The [Telegram API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) says I need to use & amp; (without the space) to replace & but either I don't understand something or it doesn't work.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/"+botID+"/sendMessage?chat_id="+chatid+"&text="+movieSearch+"&parse_mode=HTML")
```

And movieSearch is:

```
movieSearch = ("https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date="+year+"-01-01,2018-12-31&user_rating="+score+",&genres="+genres)
```

You can see that in movieSearch after the release_date there is &user_rating=... and so on. However, the bot will only send the URL until just before that & character (so until "2018-12-31").

I've tried replacing & with & amp; but it still won't send the whole URL. I've tried without the parse_mode=HTML but it didn't work either.

Comment: you have a `,` next to the `&genres`.. get rid of the comma

Comment: @johnashu Here's an example of a real URL and it has the comma too, I tried removing it but it doesn't have an effect: https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=1990-01-01,2018-12-31&user_rating=8.0,&genres=action,adventure,comedy

Comment: What happens when you try the link you posted instead of `movieSearch` into the request..

Comment: What if you escape it as `&amp;`

Comment: @johnashu it sends: https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=1990-01-01,2018-12-31

Comment: @PauloScardine if I simply replace & with `&amp;`, it does the same as with &

Comment: You must escape it as `%26amp;` instead. This is because you are not letting the requests library escape it for you.

Comment: @PauloScardine wow, `%26amp;` worked. Had no idea the requests library had an effect, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/"+botID+"/sendMessage?chat_id="
             +chatid+"&text="+movieSearch+"&parse_mode=HTML")
```

Do this:

```
params = {
    "chat_id": chatid,
    "text": movieSearch,
    "parse_mode": "HTML",
}

requests.get(
    "https://api.telegram.org/{}/sendMessage".format(botID),
    params=params
)
```

I think the problem happens because you have `&` in the value of the "text" parameter in the URL but are not escaping it as `%26`. It is better to use a dictionary instead and let the `requests` library escape it for you. You still have to escape the `&` as `&amp;`:

```
movieSearch = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date={}"
              "-01-01,2018-12-31&amp;user_rating={}&amp;genres={}".format(
                    year, score, genres)
```

Comment: Alright thank you sir. Escaping as `%26amp;` works, I'm gonna use the dictionary from now on as well.

Answer (score 0):

you sholud use the `ASCII Encoding` of char.

more info:
[URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)